# SSRS Group Rows ONLY IF There are multiple things to group

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a grid of documents that links to each document's related documents:

```
Document |         ...        | Related
------------------------------------
doc1     | ...doc1metadata... | doc1related1
doc1     | ...doc1metadata... | doc1related2
doc1     | ...doc1metadata... | doc1related3
doc1     | ...doc1metadata... | doc1related4
doc2     | ...doc2metadata... | doc2related1
doc3     | ...doc3metadata... | (null)
```

My goal is to make the grid "collapsible": that is, to have a "+" next to the first column, so that on a click, the grid will expand and show all of the related documents:

```
Document |         ...        | Related
------------------------------------
+ doc1   | ...doc1metadata... | 
+ doc2   | ...doc2metadata... | 
+ doc3   | ...doc3metadata... |
```

which goes to:

```
Document |         ...        | Related
------------------------------------
- doc1   |                    | 
         |                    | doc1related1
         |                    | doc1related2
         |                    | doc1related3
         |                    | doc1related4
+ doc2   | ...doc2metadata... | 
+ doc3   | ...doc3metadata... |
```

I can actually achieve that goal fairly easily with grouping.  However, what I would really like is for the grid to look like this:

```
Document |         ...        | Related
------------------------------------
+ doc1   | ...doc1metadata... | 
+ doc2   | ...doc2metadata... | 
  doc3   | ...doc3metadata... |
```

That is, there should be no "+" next to "doc3" because it has no related documents.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.

Try this:

Add a blank column. Set there the expand/collapse functionality. Set the textbox visibility to hidden if group has no related documents (using an appropriate function)